# Capybara; clicking on some element that is very similar to other one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

in my css I have

```
<ul class="test1">
  <li class="items">
    <a class="sample">
      <div class="itembox">
        <div class="item_name">
          <p>
            Item_name_1
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="items">
    <a class="sample">
      <div class="itembox">
        <div class="item_name">
          <p>
            Item_name_2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="items"></li>
  <li class="items"></li>
</ul>
```

as you can see, all my li(s) have the same class and their child also.
I wonder how can I click all  in my li.
if I do page.find("ul[class='test'] > li[class='items'] > a[class='sample']).click, it would found 4 elements.

**so, how can I click on "ul > li > a" by using their text in "ul > li > a > div > div > p" to specific which one?**

**Something like, click on "ul > li > a" where "ul > li > a > div > div > p", :text => "Item_name_1"**

Comment: good idea to avoid chains of HTML selectors where possible, you'll fall into the same trap of tightly tying yourself to DOM structure that css authors often fall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the link text is unique, you could simply use the `click_link` method. This method allows you to click a link based on its text. Note that its text is considered the concatentation of all text nodes within it - ie you have link texts "Item_name_1" and "Item_name_2".

```
# Click the first link
click_link('Item_name_1')

# Click the second link
click_link('Item_name_2')
```

Alternatively, if you need more control (such as needing to specify the class of the link), you could use the `find` method with the `:text` option. For example, you could locate the links with a CSS-locator and then use the `:text` option to differentiate them:

```
# Click the first link
find('a.sample', :text => 'Item_name_1').click

# Click the second link
find('a.sample', :text => 'Item_name_2').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`//li[.//p[text()='Item_name_1']]`